# Timer function not working correctly when stopped and started multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

First of all, you can find an example of my code in [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/JocaPinto/dh5hxcdd/1/) and also below the question.

I'm working on a personal training webapp and basically you can hit play and then you get five minutes to do a series of tasks in a random order. The program creates the `sessionTasks` array in which are put in a random order tasks for the `tasks` array in order to fit the five minute limit. Right now the `tasks` array is just one I created with four tasks and the respective times just for testing.

The problem I ran into is the following: When you click the task so you can move forward to the next task, the next time you play seconds will move faster. The way I found to replicate is:

1. Click play.
2. Power through the tasks by clicking the task text very quickly.
3. Click play again.

Now the seconds should be moving quicker. If not, repeat what you just did. It is irregular but it usually does it in the second try.

I cannot for the life of me understand why it behaves like this. I thought that maybe it was creating more Timers that all used `#taskTimer` to run but that didn't make sense to me. Is it something wrong with the `Timer` function? What is wrong in my code?

```js
mainMenu();


var totalSessionTasks, taskIterator, selectedTimeInSecs = 300;

var taskTimer = new Timer("#taskTimer", nextTask);

var globalTimer = new Timer("#globalTimer", function() {

});

var tasks = [
  ["First task", 0, 30],
  ["Second task", 0, 15],
  ["Third task", 0, 10],
  ["Fourth task", 3, 0]
];

var sessionTasks = [

]




function setUpSession() {

  sessionTasks = []

  if (tasks.length != 0) {

    var sessionTasksSeconds = 0; //the seconds of the session being filled
    var sessionTasksSecondsToFill = selectedTimeInSecs; //seconds left in the session to fill
    var newTaskSeconds = 0; //seconds of the next task being added to the session
    var sessionFull = false;

    console.log('Session Empty');

    while (sessionFull === false) {

      var areThereAnyTaskThatFitInTheSession =
        tasks.some(function(item) {
          return ((item[1] * 60 + item[2]) <= sessionTasksSecondsToFill) && (item != sessionTasks[sessionTasks.length - 1]);
        });
      console.log(areThereAnyTaskThatFitInTheSession);

      if (areThereAnyTaskThatFitInTheSession) {
        do {
          var randTaskNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * tasks.length);
        } while (((tasks[randTaskNum][1] * 60 + tasks[randTaskNum][2]) > sessionTasksSecondsToFill) || (tasks[randTaskNum] == sessionTasks[sessionTasks.length - 1]))

        sessionTasks.push(tasks[randTaskNum]);
        newTaskSeconds = (tasks[randTaskNum][1]) * 60 + tasks[randTaskNum][2];
        sessionTasksSecondsToFill -= newTaskSeconds;
        sessionTasksSeconds += newTaskSeconds;

        console.log(tasks[randTaskNum][0] + ": " + newTaskSeconds + "s");
        console.log(sessionTasksSeconds)

      } else if (sessionTasks.length == 0) {
        note("All your tasks are too big for a game of " + selectedTimeInSecs / 60 + " minutes!");
        break;
      } else {
        console.log('Session full');
        sessionFull = true;
        taskIterator = -1;
        totalSessionTasks = sessionTasks.length;
        console.log(totalSessionTasks);

        globalTimer.set(0, sessionTasksSeconds);
        nextTask();
        globalTimer.run();
        taskTimer.run();
      }


    }

  } else {
    note("You don't have have any tasks in your playlists!");
  }

}


function nextTask() {

  if (taskIterator + 1 < totalSessionTasks) {
    taskIterator++;
    $("#taskText").text(sessionTasks[taskIterator][0]);
    globalTimer.subtract(0, taskTimer.getTotalTimeInSeconds())
    taskTimer.set(sessionTasks[taskIterator][1], sessionTasks[taskIterator][2]);
    $("#taskCounter").text(taskIterator + 1 + " of " + totalSessionTasks + " tasks");
  } else {
    mainMenu();
    taskTimer.stop();
    globalTimer.stop();
    note("Thanks for playing!");
  }


}

//timer object function
function Timer(element, callback) {

  var ac, minutes, seconds, finalTimeInSeconds, displayMinutes, displaySeconds, interval = 1000,
    self = this,
    timeLeftToNextSecond = 1000;
  this.running = false;

  this.set = function(inputMinutes, inputSeconds) {

    finalTimeInSeconds = inputMinutes * 60 + inputSeconds;
    minutes = (Math.floor(finalTimeInSeconds / 60));
    seconds = finalTimeInSeconds % 60;

    this.print();
  }

  this.add = function(inputMinutes, inputSeconds) {

    finalTimeInSeconds += inputMinutes * 60 + inputSeconds;
    finalTimeInSeconds = (finalTimeInSeconds < 0) ? 0 : finalTimeInSeconds;
    minutes = (Math.floor(finalTimeInSeconds / 60));
    seconds = finalTimeInSeconds % 60;

    this.print();
  }

  this.subtract = function(inputMinutes, inputSeconds) {

    finalTimeInSeconds -= inputMinutes * 60 + inputSeconds;
    if (finalTimeInSeconds <= 0) {
      callback()
    }
    finalTimeInSeconds = (finalTimeInSeconds < 0) ? 0 : finalTimeInSeconds;
    minutes = (Math.floor(finalTimeInSeconds / 60));
    seconds = finalTimeInSeconds % 60;
    this.print();
  }

  this.reset = function() {

    this.set(0, 0);
  }

  this.print = function() {

    displayMinutes = (minutes.toString().length == 1) ? "0" + minutes : minutes; //ternary operator: adds a zero to the beggining 
    displaySeconds = (seconds.toString().length == 1) ? "0" + seconds : seconds; //of the number if it has only one caracter.

    $(element).text(displayMinutes + ":" + displaySeconds);
  }

  this.run = function() {

    if (this.running == false) {
      this.running = true;

      var _f = function() {
        secondStarted = new Date;
        self.subtract(0, 1);
        interval = 1000;
      }
      ac = setInterval(_f, interval);


    }
  }

  this.stop = function() {

    if (this.running == true) {
      this.running = false;
      console.log(this + "(" + element + ") was stopped");
      stopped = new Date;
      interval = 1000 - (stopped - secondStarted);
      clearInterval(ac);
    }
  }

  this.getTotalTimeInSeconds = function() {


    return finalTimeInSeconds;
  }

  this.reset();

}

function note(string) {
  alert(string);
}

function mainMenu() {
  //EMPTY BODY
  $("body").empty();
  $("body").append(
    //BUTTONS
    "<div id='playButton' class='mainButton'><div class='buttonText mainButtonText'>PLAY</div></div>"
  );
  //BINDS
  $("#playButton").bind("click", function(){
   playMain();
    setUpSession();
  });

}

function playMain() {
  //EMPTY BODY
  $("body").empty();
  $("body").append(
    //TASK TEXT
    "<p class='text' id='taskText'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>",
    //TIMERS
    "<div id='taskTimerWrap'><p class='text timer' id='taskTimer'>00:00</p><p class='text' id='taskTimerText'>Task Time</p></div>",
    "<div id='globalTimerWrap'><p class='text timer' id='globalTimer'>00:00</p><p class='text' id='globalTimerText'>Global Time</p></div>",
    //TASK COUNTER
    "<div class='text' id='taskCounter'>0/0 tasks completed</div>"
  );
  //BINDS
  $("#taskText").bind("click", nextTask);
}
```

```css
#taskText {
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 65px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#taskTimerWrap {
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 170px;
  margin: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.timer {
  font-size: 64px;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 0.88;
}

#taskTimerText {
  font-size: 34.4px;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 0.65;
}

#globalTimerWrap {
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 170px;
  margin: 5px;
  position: absolute;
}

#globalTimerText {
  font-size: 28.5px;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 0.78;
  transform: scale(1, 1.2);
}

#taskCounter {
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #98D8D9;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#taskCounter:hover {
  color: #F1F2F0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Timer.stop()` you change the interval that's used for the next run. Changing the interval variable in `_f()` isn't going to change the interval used by `setInterval()`.

In this case you will have to use `setTimeout()` instead:

```
function Timer(element, callback) {    
  var ac, minutes, seconds, finalTimeInSeconds, displayMinutes, displaySeconds, timeout = 1000,
    self = this,
    timeLeftToNextSecond = 1000;
  this.running = false;

  /* ... */

  this.run = function() {
    if (this.running == false) {
      this.running = true;

      var _f = function() {
        secondStarted = new Date;
        self.subtract(0, 1);        
        ac = setTimeout(_f, 1000);
      }
      ac = setTimeout(_f, timeout);
    }
  }

  this.stop = function() {    
    if (this.running == true) {
      this.running = false;
      console.log(this + "(" + element + ") was stopped");
      stopped = new Date;
      timeout = 1000 - (stopped - secondStarted);
      clearTimeout(ac);
    }
  }

  /* ... */    
}
```

Comment: that line is needed though

Comment: the problem only started to happen when I added the functionality of clic.king the task text to get to the next task, that line already existed

Comment: @JocaPinto What's that line even supposed to do? Yeah, that's because without clicking the task,  `stopped - secondStarted` will always be `0`.

Comment: that line makes it so that when you stop the timer in the middle of the second it will resume there instead of waiting one whole second.

Comment: @JocaPinto You can't use `setInterval` in that case, check my updated answer

Comment: I found out that actually your answer was right. I'm sorry and thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an update in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dh5hxcdd/3/)

The problem is on the variable `interval` of `Timer`

This line creates unpredictable interval under `Timer.stop()`:

```
interval = 1000 - (stopped - secondStarted);
```

If you would like to shorten the time interval, you can add a `play_count` property:

```
    ...

    //timer object function
    function Timer(element, callback) {

  var ac, minutes, seconds, finalTimeInSeconds, displayMinutes, displaySeconds, interval = 1000,
    self = this,
    timeLeftToNextSecond = 1000;

  this.running = false;
 play_count = 0;  // play count property

...

  this.run = function() {

    if (this.running == false) {
      this.running = true;

      var _f = function() {
        secondStarted = new Date;
        self.subtract(0, 1);
        interval = Math.max(1000 - play_count * 100, 500);  // ** <-- shorten time interval
      }
      ac = setInterval(_f, interval);


    }
  }

  this.stop = function() {

    if (this.running == true) {
      this.running = false;
      console.log(this + "(" + element + ") was stopped");
//      stopped = new Date;
//      interval = 1000 - (stopped - secondStarted);
            play_count++;
      clearInterval(ac);
    }
  }

  this.getTotalTimeInSeconds = function() {


    return finalTimeInSeconds;
  }

  this.reset();

}
...
```

Comment: Does my answer fit your intention?

Comment: He provided a JS Fiddle, just try your changes there and you will know does it fit or not. (I tried your changes in fiddle but didn't work, so you can better try the fiddle yourself and save & share your fiddle link when it's working.)

Answer (score 1):

As I see, you are trying to set the value for variable `interval` from inside the interval callback function.

```
      var _f = function() {
        secondStarted = new Date;
        self.subtract(0, 1);
        //interval = 1000; REMOVE THIS LINE
      }
      interval = 1000; //ADD IT HERE
      ac = setInterval(_f, interval);
```

Actually when `setInterval` is executed, the value for `interval` is not **1000**. It's not updated by `_f` yet, because that function will run after the `setInterval()` is executed. And once `setInterval()` is called with the existing value of `interval`, changing it later has no impact on the created interval, because the `setInterval()` function has already set the delay time for the interval created. And the value for `interval` changes from it's initial value **1000** because of this line :

```
 interval = 1000 - (stopped - secondStarted); //I'm not sure what you are trying to do with this, possibly removing this line will also fix your problem.)
```

## Complete Working Demo:

And here is the [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dh5hxcdd/2/).

```js
mainMenu();


var totalSessionTasks, taskIterator, selectedTimeInSecs = 300;

var taskTimer = new Timer("#taskTimer", nextTask);

var globalTimer = new Timer("#globalTimer", function() {

});

var tasks = [
  ["First task", 0, 30],
  ["Second task", 0, 15],
  ["Third task", 0, 10],
  ["Fourth task", 3, 0]
];

var sessionTasks = [

]




function setUpSession() {

  sessionTasks = []

  if (tasks.length != 0) {

    var sessionTasksSeconds = 0; //the seconds of the session being filled
    var sessionTasksSecondsToFill = selectedTimeInSecs; //seconds left in the session to fill
    var newTaskSeconds = 0; //seconds of the next task being added to the session
    var sessionFull = false;

    console.log('Session Empty');

    while (sessionFull === false) {

      var areThereAnyTaskThatFitInTheSession =
        tasks.some(function(item) {
          return ((item[1] * 60 + item[2]) <= sessionTasksSecondsToFill) && (item != sessionTasks[sessionTasks.length - 1]);
        });
      console.log(areThereAnyTaskThatFitInTheSession);

      if (areThereAnyTaskThatFitInTheSession) {
        do {
          var randTaskNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * tasks.length);
        } while (((tasks[randTaskNum][1] * 60 + tasks[randTaskNum][2]) > sessionTasksSecondsToFill) || (tasks[randTaskNum] == sessionTasks[sessionTasks.length - 1]))

        sessionTasks.push(tasks[randTaskNum]);
        newTaskSeconds = (tasks[randTaskNum][1]) * 60 + tasks[randTaskNum][2];
        sessionTasksSecondsToFill -= newTaskSeconds;
        sessionTasksSeconds += newTaskSeconds;

        console.log(tasks[randTaskNum][0] + ": " + newTaskSeconds + "s");
        console.log(sessionTasksSeconds)

      } else if (sessionTasks.length == 0) {
        note("All your tasks are too big for a game of " + selectedTimeInSecs / 60 + " minutes!");
        break;
      } else {
        console.log('Session full');
        sessionFull = true;
        taskIterator = -1;
        totalSessionTasks = sessionTasks.length;
        console.log(totalSessionTasks);

        globalTimer.set(0, sessionTasksSeconds);
        nextTask();
        globalTimer.run();
        taskTimer.run();
      }


    }

  } else {
    note("You don't have have any tasks in your playlists!");
  }

}


function nextTask() {

  if (taskIterator + 1 < totalSessionTasks) {
    taskIterator++;
    $("#taskText").text(sessionTasks[taskIterator][0]);
    globalTimer.subtract(0, taskTimer.getTotalTimeInSeconds())
    taskTimer.set(sessionTasks[taskIterator][1], sessionTasks[taskIterator][2]);
    $("#taskCounter").text(taskIterator + 1 + " of " + totalSessionTasks + " tasks");
  } else {
    mainMenu();
    taskTimer.stop();
    globalTimer.stop();
    note("Thanks for playing!");
  }


}

//timer object function
function Timer(element, callback) {

  var ac, minutes, seconds, finalTimeInSeconds, displayMinutes, displaySeconds, interval = 1000,
    self = this,
    timeLeftToNextSecond = 1000;
  this.running = false;

  this.set = function(inputMinutes, inputSeconds) {

    finalTimeInSeconds = inputMinutes * 60 + inputSeconds;
    minutes = (Math.floor(finalTimeInSeconds / 60));
    seconds = finalTimeInSeconds % 60;

    this.print();
  }

  this.add = function(inputMinutes, inputSeconds) {

    finalTimeInSeconds += inputMinutes * 60 + inputSeconds;
    finalTimeInSeconds = (finalTimeInSeconds < 0) ? 0 : finalTimeInSeconds;
    minutes = (Math.floor(finalTimeInSeconds / 60));
    seconds = finalTimeInSeconds % 60;

    this.print();
  }

  this.subtract = function(inputMinutes, inputSeconds) {

    finalTimeInSeconds -= inputMinutes * 60 + inputSeconds;
    if (finalTimeInSeconds <= 0) {
      callback()
    }
    finalTimeInSeconds = (finalTimeInSeconds < 0) ? 0 : finalTimeInSeconds;
    minutes = (Math.floor(finalTimeInSeconds / 60));
    seconds = finalTimeInSeconds % 60;
    this.print();
  }

  this.reset = function() {

    this.set(0, 0);
  }

  this.print = function() {

    displayMinutes = (minutes.toString().length == 1) ? "0" + minutes : minutes; //ternary operator: adds a zero to the beggining 
    displaySeconds = (seconds.toString().length == 1) ? "0" + seconds : seconds; //of the number if it has only one caracter.

    $(element).text(displayMinutes + ":" + displaySeconds);
  }

  this.run = function() {

    if (this.running == false) {
      this.running = true;

      var _f = function() {
        secondStarted = new Date;
        self.subtract(0, 1);
        //interval = 1000; REMOVE THIS LINE
      }
      interval = 1000; //ADD IT HERE
      ac = setInterval(_f, interval);


    }
  }

  this.stop = function() {

    if (this.running == true) {
      this.running = false;
      console.log(this + "(" + element + ") was stopped");
      stopped = new Date;
      interval = 1000 - (stopped - secondStarted);
      clearInterval(ac);
    }
  }

  this.getTotalTimeInSeconds = function() {


    return finalTimeInSeconds;
  }

  this.reset();

}

function note(string) {
  alert(string);
}

function mainMenu() {
  //EMPTY BODY
  $("body").empty();
  $("body").append(
    //BUTTONS
    "<div id='playButton' class='mainButton'><div class='buttonText mainButtonText'>PLAY</div></div>"
  );
  //BINDS
  $("#playButton").bind("click", function(){
   playMain();
    setUpSession();
  });

}

function playMain() {
  //EMPTY BODY
  $("body").empty();
  $("body").append(
    //TASK TEXT
    "<p class='text' id='taskText'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>",
    //TIMERS
    "<div id='taskTimerWrap'><p class='text timer' id='taskTimer'>00:00</p><p class='text' id='taskTimerText'>Task Time</p></div>",
    "<div id='globalTimerWrap'><p class='text timer' id='globalTimer'>00:00</p><p class='text' id='globalTimerText'>Global Time</p></div>",
    //TASK COUNTER
    "<div class='text' id='taskCounter'>0/0 tasks completed</div>"
  );
  //BINDS
  $("#taskText").bind("click", nextTask);
}
```

```css
#taskText {
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  top: 50px;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 65px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#taskTimerWrap {
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 170px;
  margin: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.timer {
  font-size: 64px;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 0.88;
}

#taskTimerText {
  font-size: 34.4px;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 0.65;
}

#globalTimerWrap {
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 170px;
  margin: 5px;
  position: absolute;
}

#globalTimerText {
  font-size: 28.5px;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 0.78;
  transform: scale(1, 1.2);
}

#taskCounter {
  text-align: center;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #98D8D9;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

#taskCounter:hover {
  color: #F1F2F0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```